# How do I make a Stack Exchange site without going through the whole Area 51 thing?

Tags: discussion

I really want an answer for this since I don't know how to make an Stack Exchange site.

I want to make one just for myself and my friends and my friends' friends. Is there any way I can do this?

I saw something saying that you can make a Stack Exchange for free, but I don't know if that's true.

Comment: No not really, I don't really understand. I saw something about it being free or something.

Comment: You can't the software is propitiatory. You can pay for teams on SO like in the above comment or use Area 51 to suggest a site. Where exactly did you see this?

Comment: I don't know, thanks for answering. That solves the question

Comment: Did you happen to see [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/are-there-any-clones-alternatives-for-running-a-stack-exchange-style-qa-site/37953#37953) and thought it means you can have "Stack Exchange" for free?

Comment: I had a quick look around and found a whole load of open source clones. I am not sure of their legitimacy or quality, so won't link them here but you can Google for "Stack Exchange clone free" and then you could host one yourself for privet use.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2267/248731

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by @Mark Kirby.

> "You can't the software is propitiatory. You can pay for teams on SO like in the above comment or use Area 51 to suggest a site. Where exactly did you see this?" ([Go to comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/355946/how-do-i-make-a-stack-exchange-without-going-through-the-whole-area-51-thing/355947#comment1189634_355946))

Comment: *[proprietary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/proprietary)*